# Invalid XML issues with a link

Tags: asp.net, xml

I'm trying to drop the following link into an XML file and it is kicking back an error.

```
<link URL="http://hqgoogle1/search?site=bolt_collection&client=bolt_frontend&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=bolt_frontend&proxycustom=%3cHOME/" TitleText="" LinkText="BOLT" />
```

Error:

This is an unexpected token. The expected token is 'SEMICOLON'. Line 47, position 69.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. The link is valid and works fine. Is there something with the "&c" that break the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `&` is the prefix for an entity, which must be terminated with a `;`. Simply replace all `&`s with `&amp;` in your attributes. `&amp;` represents an `&` in XML.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out and came back here to post, but you had already beaten me to it.